# Evolution Operator with Perturbation Integral Formulation

Tags: quantum-mechanics, operators, perturbation-theory, time-evolution, propagator

Cohen-Tannoudji's Atom-Photon Interactions book claims on page 167 that

$U(t, t')=U_0(t, t') + \frac{1}{i \hbar}\int_{t'}^{t}dt_1 U_0(t, t_1)VU(t_1, t') $ satisfies

$i \hbar \ d/dtU(t, t') = (H_0+V)U(t, t')$
with $U(t', t')=1$ and $U_0(t, t')=e^{-iH_0 (t-t')/\hbar}$

where V is a perturbation to the Hamiltonian. However, I can't get this to work when I plug the integral equation in.

I get instead

$i \hbar \ d/dtU(t, t') = i \hbar \ d/dt(U_0(t, t') + \frac{1}{i \hbar}\int_{t'}^{t}dt_1 U_0(t, t_1)VU(t_1, t') ) = H_0 U_0(t,t') + VU(t, t')$ which does not appear to be equal to $(H_0+V)U(t, t')$

Does anyone see the resolution to this?

Comment: Is there a derivative missing in the equation for $U(t,t^\prime)$? Further, it would help if you would include your calculations.

Comment: Have you used the [Leibniz integral rule](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Leibniz_integral_rule)?

Comment: Oops! Noted and edited in response to your first comment, thank you! Can you elaborate on the second comment?

Comment: Well, check the Wikipedia page... I think that you can readily apply this equation to obtain the correct result. You just have to rename variables after all.

Comment: Have you managed to arrive at the desired result?

Comment: Yes, thanks for your help! :)